# Shortest Distance Between Pair of Beetles on a Cube

Tags: word-problem

This is a problem from the AMT (an Australian paper) from 2011:

[image]

The first thing I thought was when the first beetle was directly over the line FH or the second beetle directly over AC, the distance would be at a minimum. I could create a function (somehow utilizing the different rates and actually finding a way to get that distance as a function) and find that minimum, but this paper didn't require any complicated formulas or extra "stuff", so Pythagoras was probably the only formula you needed to know. I was a bit stuck as to how I should continue, trying out just simple cases and seeing where that would take me, however, that didn't work. Does anyone have any insights/methods to do this problem?

Comment: Figure out the formulas for the locations of both beetles at time $t$ (make $t=0$ match the instant they start moving). Then use Pythagoras to write the square of their distance as a function of $t$. It will be a quadratic polynomial on $t$. You can then figure out the instant of the minimum distance, either by completing square or by differentiating. Then you are basically done.

Comment: I guess it is easier to use FH as x-axis, AC as y-axis and FB as the z-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the figure:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

Let $HJ=s, AK=2s$. Then the distance $KJ$ is:
$$d(s)=\sqrt{LO^2+JO^2+KL^2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{80\sqrt{55}}2-2s\right)^2+\left(\frac{80\sqrt{55}}2-s\right)^2+(40\sqrt{110})^2}.\\
(d^2(s))'=-4\left(40\sqrt{55}-2s\right)-2\left(40\sqrt{55}-s\right)\Rightarrow 10s=240\sqrt{55} \Rightarrow s=24\sqrt{55}\\
(d^2(s))''=10>0 \ \Rightarrow \text{min}$$
Hence:
$$d(24\sqrt{55})=440.$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a hint to make the straightforward attack a bit less work.

Note that in the Eucliden distance formula for the distance between the two beetles, the difference in their $z$ coordinates (taking the $z$-axis parallel to $BF$) is constant ($z_1 - z_2 = 40 \sqrt{110}$ always).  The distance is minimized when the square of the distance is minimized.  The $z$ contribution to the squared distance ($(z_1 - z_2)^2 = 1600 \cdot 110$) is constant and a constant offset does not alter the location of a minimum.  Consequently, you can pretend the two beetles are in the plane (both having $z = 0$) and find the shortest separation distance there, then displace them in the $z$ direction to find out their shortest separation distance on their original paths.

Comment: To simplify even more the above: once we look at the motion of the beetles in a plane, you can switch to the reference frame of the second beetle (that now stands still at the origin in its own frame of reference): ie, the second beetle has now a relative velocity as its own minus the velocity vector of  the 1st beetle. This relative velocity defines the line on which the beetle moves and you can now compute the minimum distance between the origin (where the 1st beetle stands) and the line using analytical geometry. Lastly, you add the vertical distance (as per above comment).